# Change $scope variable on Angular form checkbox change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a variable set on $scope `$scope.some_val` that I want to update on form submission depending on whether a checkbox is checked or not.

I want to hold on to the original value `some_val` but only update it when user clicks submit.

I tried:

`ng-model="some_model.some_val" ng-true-value="new_val" ng-false-value="{{ some_model.some_val }}"`

Because I want the original value preserved but this didn't work.
How can I do this?

Comment: This feels like an XY problem to me. It's not clear what you are really trying to accomplish; With angular two way binding, the need to update on submit is very rarely necessary, and it's even less necessary to only *sometimes* update a value.  can you show the use case you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Angular does not accept non-constant expressions in the `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` attributes, as stated in [this doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/constexpr?p0=ngTrueValue&p1=).

What I would invite you to try is to simply hardcode the default value in a regular JavaScript variable, in the controller behind the form. On user submit, just check if the checkbox has been checked and if so - update the value. If not - reassign it to the hardcoded JS var.

Below is the working code and here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hxc8Ge?p=preview).

```js
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('controller', function($scope){
  var origin_value = 'original value';
  $scope.some_val = origin_value;
  $scope.submit = function(input){
    if(input.checkbox) 
      $scope.some_val = input.text;
    else
      $scope.some_val = origin_value;
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/angular.js/1.4.0-beta.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <code>{{some_val}}</code>
  <form novalidate>
    <input ng-model="input.text" name="input" type="text" /><br/>
    Update some_val? <input type="checkbox" value="checked" ng-model="input.checkbox" name="checkbox" required="" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="submit(input)" value="save"/>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you and have a nice day!